# Converting __m256d mask to __m128i mask

Tags: c++, simd, avx

I obtain a __m256d mask using
`__m256d _mm256_cmp_pd (__m256d a, __m256d b, const int imm8)`
since the `a` and `b` are loaded from two `std::vector<double>`. I then need to use this mask to maskstore 4 doubles (held in __256d) and 4 ints of size 32bit (held in __128i).

For the doubles, I use `void _mm256_maskstore_pd (double * mem_addr, __m256i mask, __m256d a)` by casting my __256d mask into a __256i mask with `__m256i _mm256_castpd_si256 (__m256d a)`. This works as expected.

For the ints, I cannot find the correct way to convert the __m256d mask to the equivalent __m128i mask in order to use `void _mm_maskstore_epi32 (int* mem_addr, __m128i mask, __m128i a)`. My current attempt, which runs but gives incorrect results, uses `_mm_castpd_si128(_mm256_castpd256_pd128(__256dmask))`. What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: Obviously you need a shuffle to get 4x 32-bit elements from your 4x 64-bit elements, not just taking the low half of your 256-bit vector.  That would use each 64-bit mask element as a pair of 32-bit elements.  One way to get all 4 elements into the low 128 would be `vextracti128` / `vpblendd`, but that wouldn't leave them in the right order.  So probably just use `vpermd` with a shuffle-control vector that grabs a dword from each qword.  (Assuming you have AVX2 since you said you're using `_mm_maskstore_epi32` not `_ps`).

Comment: I would do it like that: https://gist.github.com/Const-me/bdcdfc24734f0477e7aab3c2326af562 It compiles into 2 instructions. `_mm_shuffle_ps` is very fast one, and this method doesn’t need any RAM references.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers!